# Error 405: Request method POST not supported

Tags: java, json, rest, postman, spring-annotations

Initially my request object for calling rest service was:-

```
public class RequestParamDto {
   private String tokenID;
   private String taxID;
   private String affiliateID;
   private long planID;
   private String participantId;
   private String[] participantIdArr;
}
```

and corresponding JSON request object is:-

```
{
   "tokenID": "12356446",
   "taxID": "123456",
   "planID": 123456,
   "affiliateID": "7876675901282905002"
}
```

I am passing some parameters in header section of POSTMAN CLIENT-

```
x-username:abc126
x-enterpriseid:F1111
x-uniqueid:4T5646464
x-ris-audienceview:emplabc
Content-Type:application/json
Accept:application/json
```

Above request is working fine with POSTMAN CLIENT.

Right now my request object contains list of custom objects.It will look like this:

```
public class ContributionsRequestParamDto {

  private String tokenID;
  private String taxID;
  private String affiliateID;
  private long planID;
  private String accountNumber;
  private String bankAccountNumber;
  private String transitId;
  private BigDecimal eftAmt;
  private Date ppeDate;
  private String taxYear;
  private Short planType;
  private List<ParticipantsDeferralDto> participantsDeferrals;
  private List<EmployersContributionDto> employersContributions;
}
```

and its corresponding JSON request object is:

```
   {
      "tokenID" : "123456789",
      "taxID" : "123456",
      "affiliateID" : "123456789",
      "planID" : 123456,
      "ppeDate" : "2017-10-24",
      "taxYear" : "2017",
      "planType" : 1,
      "participantsDeferrals" : [ {
        "taxId" : "555555",
        "participantDeferralAmt" : 22.00
      } ],
      "employersContributions" : [ {
        "taxId" : "555555",
        "employerContributionAmt" : 22.00
      } ]
    }
```

For above request I am passing same parameters in header section. 
I am getting `Error 405: Request method &#39;POST&#39; not supported` error. I am trying to hit this request with `http://api100.abc.xyz.com:9080/abcd/api/sscws/v1/saveContributions` URL. Am I doing anything wrong for this request or I missed something? 
Thanks!

EDIT -
My REST function that I want to call is-

```
@Transactional
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
@Api(value="v1", description="")
public class SscRestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/saveContributions", 
            method=RequestMethod.POST, produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, consumes={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    @ApiOperation(value="Returns the saved contributions object")
    public String saveContributions(@RequestBody ContributionsRequestParam contributionsParam) throws Exception {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share you request mapping or what you use to create the endpoint?

Comment: @sfat - Please check REST endpoint in edit section and suggest me if I am doing anything wrong there. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "ContributionsRequestParamDto.java" I have declared ppeDate as Date. I have changed it to String and it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

405 Error simply says that  endpoint is not accepting the request with specified Http Method. in your case it is POST.

Please verify if REST endpoint  is listening to the POST method with given content-type.

This error has nothing to do with complexity of JSON object.

Comment: for rest endpoint I have updated this question. Please check edit section for REST Endpoint

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's a typo or maybe I'm wrong but you have ContributionsRequestParam**Dto** as dto you want to accept, but your endpoint method saveContributions(..) takes ContributionsRequestParam as @RequestBody

Comment: This will probbly be the next problem he will encounter. But right now upper layer is bouncing back with unsupported method. Next he will get 400 bad request because of what you have pointed out

Comment: @stejskys - Thanks, but the first request is working fine. For first request also I am doing the same. I don't think it will work, but I will try your solution.

Comment: @stejskys - your solution is not working. I tried it